# is impersonation what i'm looking for

Tags: c#, asp.net

My workstation is inside my company network domain. I have a virtual pc on my workstation that is not on the domain and my asp.net web application is windows authenticated which resides on the virtual.

can't i use impersonation and use my network credentials to access the domain thru the application?

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no - impersonation is all about allowing your asp.net web app to run as a different user, but one that is still inside the domain / forest

you might be able to get it to work via NTLM. Create a user on the virtual machine with the same user name and password as your domain account

Comment: do have to change the workgroup? like maybe to match the domain?

Answer (score 1):

You could put your domain creds in code:

[Using programmatic Impersonation from an ASP.NET Page](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2005/Feb/24/Using-programmatic-Impersonation-from-an-ASPNET-Page)